# How to execute a :g style command with a range in Vim

Tags: vim

With Vim, if I want to delete every line which has the text `pending` I can do:

```
:g/pending/d
```

How do I do this with a range? Say I want to delete every line with the text `pending` but only between lines 0 and 60 (or, between 0 and here) something like:

```
:0,./pending/d
```

I have searched, but I'm failing to see how to do this. I know you can do
`:0,. normal <command>` but I'm not sure what the normal mode command to conditionally delete a line is.

p.s. and where do you go in help to learn these things ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like most if not all Ex commands, `:global` takes a range. So if `:g/pending/d` does what you want on the whole buffer it will also do what you want on the given range:

```
:1,.g/pending/d
```

As for where to find out about this, well… look no further than Vim's documentation.

`:help :global` says:

```
                                                *:g* *:global* *E147* *E148*
:[range]g[lobal]/{pattern}/[cmd]
                        Execute the Ex command [cmd] (default ":p") on the
                        lines within [range] where {pattern} matches.
```

Which is pretty clear.

NOTE: lines start at `1`.

Comment: Thanks @romainl, I think I just had "global" in my head as being... global. But that's great - thanks very much.